# Python Variable doesn't rebound in for loop

Tags: python-2.7

```
employees = []
for i in range(0,10):

    emp = Employee(i)
    emp.first_name = "%s-%s"%("first name", i)
    emp.last_name = "%s-%s"%("last_name", i)
    emp.desgination = "%s-%s"%("engineer", i)

    employees.append(emp)


ids = [e.eid for e in employees]
```

Following is my class definition:

```
class Employee:

    _fields = {}

    def __init__(self, eid):
        self.eid = eid

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self._fields.get(name)

    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        self._fields[name] = value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._fields)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self._fields)
```

The issue is that when I print ids, it contains 10 times 9... i.e.

```
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

It seems that the same emp variable is being overwritten. I am not sure what going wrong. Though I am a Java coder but I thought I had a fair idea of Python as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, indeed, your java past ! :)

The error is here:

```
_fields = {}
```

`_fields` is a CLASS member ! So each instance of Employee shares the same `_fields` var, and whenever you modify one, you modify all other objects.
You must move the `_fields = {}` part into the `__init__` function :

```
self._fields={}
```

But then, you will run into another problem: `self.eid = xx` invokes the `__setattr__` method! (and so does self._fields !)

The solution is to use `self.__dict__['_fields']` when you need to access to the instance's '_fields' member instead of `self._fields`. It will directly access the member, instead of going through `__getattr__` and an infinite reccursion, with a nice stack overflow in the end.

Comment: right! thnx. is there a way I can get over the __setattr__ method issue. The point is that I want to maintain a list or dict of attributes added dynamically to the instance.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Check the following URL (older version, but still applies) : http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/attribute-access.html. It implies that you have to use self.__dict__['_fields'] instead of self._fields.

Answer (score 0):

its a side effect of the functions:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return self._fields.get(name)

def __setattr__(self,name,value):
    self._fields[name] = value
```

remove them and it works. so this is the direction to look.